# PHP CodeIgniter external API call

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm just now starting to get into the CodeIgniter framework, and am still getting used to the model-controller-view setup.

I have a controller class called "Customer" and it contains the following code of which I need access:

```
function loadCustomer(){
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $result['Success'] = 0;
    $user = $this->User->LoadUser($_POST['UserID']);
    if($user){
        $result['Success'] = 1;
            $user->Package = $this->User->GetPrimaryPackage($user->UserID);
            $user->AccountAlerts = $this->User->GetAccountAlertOptions($user->UserID);
            $_SESSION['User'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['UserLoggedIn'] = true;

            $result['User'] = $user;
            $result['UserLoggedIn'] = true;

        }

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

The model called "User" contains this:

```
function LoadUser($UserID = null){
    if(!$UserID){
        trigger_error("No userid supplied.", E_USER_ERROR);
        exit();
    }
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mydb.tblUsers where UserID='$UserID';")->row();
    if(!empty($result)){
        return $result;
    }
    else{
        return null;    
    }
}
```

I am working with the following code, where I need to be able to access the `"loadCustomer()"` function within Customer so that I can perform an auto login based on the UserID:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM incoming_calls";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $number = $row['phone_number'];
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT Username, UserID, Name
    FROM tblUsers 
    WHERE PhoneHome='$number' OR PhoneCell='$number' OR PhoneWork='$number'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userArray[] = array("name" => $row['Name'], "username" => $row['Username'], "user_id" => $row['UserID']);
}

if (!empty($userArray)) {
    echo json_encode($userArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

How do I go about this, any help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: do or at least read through the codeigniter tutorial: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html Next read through about Active Record for your database calls  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html and generating query results http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 2):

I hope your model has more then meets the eye, because the model you posted doesn't have the required class structure.

Please review this:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

CodeIgniter's doc is going to be your best friend. ... Most of the time, I had some cases where the doc was missing something, but it's pretty rare and at that point Google is your best friend.

I also recommend using CodeIgniter's session library. As it's less error/mistake prone and much easier to work with and includes some neat features...

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Example Code:

Controller:

```
class MyPage extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
          $this->load->model("user");
          $sum = $this->user->doWork(4, 4);
    }

}
```

Model

```
 class User extends CI_Model {

      function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function doWork($x, $y)
    {
      return $x + $y;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Yes, is a fully functional model, I was simply showing what I'm needing access to.

Comment: Ah, well if you just need access to the model, just review my example code I posted.